# Adding collection and subcollection data to model entity from firestore firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm recently started using Firebase firestore. I'm stuck at the point were the collection have sub collections and get those items to my model.

[image]

Let say I have this collection

```
meats
  \ id : 1
  \ name : Chicken
 subMeats 
      \ id : 11
      \ name : Country Chicken
      \ id : 12
      \ name : Broiler Chicken
meats 
  \ id : 2
  \ name : Pork
subMeats
      \ id : 21  
      \ name : White Pork
      \ id : 22
      \ name : Black Pork

     return meatTypeCollection.get().then((value) {
  value.docs.forEach((mainDoc) {
   // MainMeatEntity.fromSnapshot(mainDoc)    
    _logger.i(mainDoc.data()['name']);
    meatTypeCollection
        .doc(mainDoc.id)
        .collection('subMeats')
        .get()
        .then((snapShots) {
      snapShots.docs.forEach((doc) {
        _logger.i(doc.data()['name']);
        MainMeat.fromEntity(MainMeatEntity.fromSnapshot(doc));
      });
    });
  });
  //return MeatTypes.fromEntity(MeatTypeEntity.fromJson(value.docs));
}).catchError((error) => _logger.e("Failed to load meat types : $error"));
```

The above does not capture the collection. I use entity to model.

```
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
   import 'entities/main_meat_entity.dart';
   import 'entities/meat_type_entity.dart';

    @immutable
    class MainMeat {
    final String id;
    final String name;
    final MeatTypeEntity subMeats;
    final String shopId;

 const MainMeat({
   this.id,
   this.name,
   this.subMeats,
   this.shopId,
 });

 static MainMeat fromEntity(MainMeatEntity mainMeatEntity) {
   return MainMeat(
    id: mainMeatEntity.id,
    name: mainMeatEntity.name,
    subMeats: mainMeatEntity.subMeats,
    shopId: mainMeatEntity.shopId,
   );
  }

  MainMeatEntity toEntity() {
     return MainMeatEntity(id, name, subMeats, shopId);
  }

  static const empty = MainMeat(id: '', shopId: "", name: "");
   }
  -----------------------------****************--------------------
  part 'meat_type_entity.g.dart';

 @JsonSerializable()
 class MeatTypeEntity extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String shopId;

  const MeatTypeEntity(this.id, this.name, this.shopId);

  factory MeatTypeEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  _$MeatTypeEntityFromJson(json);

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MeatTypeEntityToJson(this);

   @override
   List<Object> get props => [
     id,
     name,
     shopId,
    ];

   static MeatTypeEntity fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    return MeatTypeEntity(
    snap.id,
    snap.data()['name'],
    snap.data()["shopId"],
      );
     }

    Map<String, Object> toDocument() {
     return {
     "id": id,
     'mainMeat': name,
     "shopId": shopId,
     };
    }
   }
```

I can list it's collection and sub collections fine. But not sure to load into my model. Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi! I don't quite understand what your struggle is here. Do you mean you don't know how you can convert firestore snapshot to Dart class?

Comment: yes, difficult to structure in my model

Comment: you have to use different models for both.

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code? If so, could you share them?

Comment: Yup, I did but hard to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store subCollection to collection directly, [Read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) FireStore data model section.

So your structure will be look like
Meal(document) -> all meal collection -> Sub Meal (document) -> all sub meals collection.

If you want to read the data like firebase database, you can't read the complete tree/hierarchy at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming this is a Dart question of how to create models, I would create something like this:

```
class Meat {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<SubMeat> subMeats;

  Meat({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
    this.subMeats,
  });
}

class SubMeat {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  SubMeat({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
  });
}
```